# Optimize: $\arg\min_{\theta>0} \quad \big\| x - \sum_{n} c_{n} \bf{k}_{n}(\theta) \big\|_{2}^{2}$

Tags: calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, parameter-estimation

Can somebody help me get started with the following problem? I want to solve:

$$\theta^* := \arg\min_{\theta>0} \quad \big\| x - \sum_{n=1}^N c_{n} \bf{k}_{n}(\theta) \big\|_{2}^{2}$$

where $x$ and $\bf{k}_{n}(\theta)$ are vectors in $\mathbb{C}^L$ such that ${\bf{k}_n=\{\bf{k}_1,\bf{k}_2,...\bf{k}_N \}}$ for a given scaling factor $\theta$.  $\bf{k}_{n}(\theta)$ are the time-shifts of a Gaussian, i.e.,generated by translating a Gaussian function $g(t)  \in {L^2(R)} $. For any $\theta >0$ and translation $n$, $\bf{k}_{n}(\theta)$ is defined as

$$k_{n}(\theta)=g \left({t-n}\right)$$

where

$$g(t)=e^{-(t/\theta)^2}$$

Comment: You should be able to find a description of a quasi Newton method in many textbooks. What was your specific question?

Comment: It's yours a smoothing problem? How $||\cdot||$ is defined?

Comment: @Cesareo $||\cdot||$ is a frobenius norm in this case.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I made some edit, is it clear now?

Comment: @copper.hat How do I solve for $\theta$?

Comment: You can for example build a neural network and do back propagation. Gaussian has nice easy to calculate derivative for the chain rule.

Comment: @mathreadler sorry but I have no idea about neural network. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: As long as I understood $k_n = k_n(t,\theta)$ so what is the role of $t$ ? There is any hidden integration?

Comment: @Cesareo $t$ is simply a time index.

Comment: Is it a constant along the process?

Comment: @Cesareo $t=1,2,....L$